# save a label from Xcode to a user in parse using swift

Tags: ios, swift, parsing

Im trying to save a label from my app to the user class thats created by parse when you use their sign up and sign in format. I've tried it multiple different ways but can't seem to find away to save the data to the User section. The class name is User and I'm trying to save a label to column labeled Score in the User class. This code is the last thing i tried to do.

@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

```
override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad() var gamescore = PFObject(className:"_User")
    gamescore["Score"] = self.Label.text
    gamescore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {

        } else {

        }
    }
```

If someone could help me that would be awesome because I'm beyond stumped on this. I tried looking up on google and youtube and even going through the parse docs on a way to do it but, can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Have you checked that self.label.text contains something at the point you are assigning it? Its in the viewDidLoad so where is the label getting its initial value from? NSLog it and check you are actually assigning something to gamescore["Score"}. And if that is ok did you check if the success branch executes or the else branch in the block, if the else branch then what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the object is successfully saving?

What I like to do for saving to the user class is to use PFUser.currentUser() to obtain the user table and save object from there.

```
let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser();
currentUser.setObject(self.Label.text,forKey:"Score");
user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success,error)-> Void in
    if(error == nil){
        println("Success");
    }
    else{
        println("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is going to work I'm just getting an error saying that user.Type does not have a member named 'saveInBackgroundWithBlock'

Comment: Should be currentUser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock: I misspelled , sorry

Comment: that got it to work! thank you! But is there a way to have it auto sync in the background so its updating the Score when the user exits the app?

Comment: You could maybe use saveEventually before the app closes which there's some functions in the app delegate .

Comment: currentUser. saveEventually{(success,error) -> Void in something like this? or how would it go?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to specify a callback if you dont like. It will save to the cloud if it can and if not because of network issues, will save automatically the next time you have connection without you having to call it again. Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/ to determine when you want to call it.